# Cannot see Simple.Data trace messages

Tags: postgresql, simple.data

I cannot seem to view the trace messages for the `Simple.Data` library.  I am using the Postgresql provider.

I have added the following to the web config to ensure all the messages will come through:

```
system.diagnostics>
    <switches>
      <add name="Simple.Data" value="4" />
    </switches>
  </system.diagnostics>
```

But still nothing.  I can see the output that I write to the trace using `Trace.Write("test");`

Tried adding a custom listener, but this also only picked up my generated messages.  Do I need to enable tracing somehow in the `Simple.Data` library?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using a numerical value for the switch level, use the name. It's more reliable.
so in your case:

```
<system.diagnostics>
    <switches>
        <add name="Simple.Data" value="Verbose" />
    </switches>
</system.diagnostics>
```

(Replace Verbose with 'Info', 'Warning', 'Error' or 'Off' as needed)

Should you wish to control the trace via code you can use SimpleDataTraceSources eg:

```
SimpleDataTraceSources.TraceSource.Switch.Level = SourceLevels.Verbose;
```